# Methods and Software for Interpolating/Modelling of Stratigraphic Well Data in 2D/3D

Tags: geology, models, stratigraphy, software, data-analysis

I have some geologic well data. The lithologies have been interpreted, and stratigraphic columns have been drawn. The columns have been adjusted for elevation, and correlation has been done between seemingly continuous layers.

Is there a more sophisticated 2D/3D program, preferably open source or free trial (I'm a student), that could be used to map the area better with an interpolated or block diagram result?

Comment: Maybe some stuff from [Golden Software](http://www.goldensoftware.com/), like Strater or Voxler?

Comment: Maybe OpendTect?

Comment: From the question is is unclear what exactly you want to map?

Comment: Which Software did you use so far (since you are looking for `more` sophisticated 2D/3D program)?

Comment: @daniel.neumann, I ended up developing a cross section tool using JavaScript and Python.

Answer (score 3):

OpendTect *may* do this, however getting to that stage would be a painful experience.

Petrel can do this very easily, however, that is not anywhere near free...

If you're a student, your department may have access to a few decent programs to achieve this. If you could find out what you have available, we might be of more help!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [Leapfrog 3D](http://www.leapfrog3d.com) will do this. They have [academic licenses](http://www.leapfrog3d.com/academic). I also seem to recall that [Intrepid Geomodeller](http://www.intrepid-geophysics.com/ig/index.php?page=geomodeller) does what you are after. Both of these options are probably overkill though.